# Are fold expressions a C++14 or a C++1z feature?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, c++17, fold-expression

https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard states that the working draft [N4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

> contains the C++14 standard plus minor editorial changes.

I noted that N4296 §5.1.3 contains a specification of "Fold expressions". I thought this to be a feature which did not make it to the official C++14 standard.

**Are fold expressions part of C++14 or is this addition in N4296 one of those *minor* editorial changes?**

Comment: c++17, but you'll find them supported in clang with -std=c++1z and supported with a warning with -std=c++14

Comment: 5.1.3 is not in C++14.  My recollection is that draft N3936 was what became the C++14 standard.

Comment: The addition of fold expressions does seem like quite a bit more than an editorial change (especially a 'minor' one).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- N3937 is the C++14 DIS (Draft International Standard). N3936 (no longer publicly available, but can be dug out from the github repo) is N3937 with a different cover.
- N4141 is the C++14 IS; it's the DIS plus some editorial changes. It's not publicly available.
- [N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) is the pre-Urbana working draft; it's N4141 plus more editorial changes.
- N4296 is the post-Urbana working draft. It includes C++17 features voted in at the committee's Urbana meeting.

Fold expressions is a C++17 feature.

Comment: Why N4141 isn't publicly available ?

Comment: The numbers are confusing. N4140 is N4141 plus more editorial changes (4140 < 4141)? Not like N39## something + editorial changes?

Comment: @jotik N3936 == N3937 (ignoring cover page). N4140 = N3936 + many editorial changes. N4141 = N3937 + a much smaller subset of those editorial changes.

Comment: Fold expressions seems to originate from [N4191](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4191.html) (dated 2014-10-07), so it clearly didn't make the standard on which the final ballot period closed in August 2014.

Comment: @Destructor Because they don't want to have the *exact* text of an international standard freely available. In practice, it doesn't matter, I don't think; simply use whatever draft immediately predates the IS.

Comment: I thought the whole point of an IS is to be publicly available, usually for a hefty fee.